# SQL query syntax issue

Tags: php, mysql

I dont know how to fix this. Where is the error? I have tried to find out and I think it has got something to do with the **AND**

```
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM photos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$queryStart.", 5" AND type="pic");
```

Comment: It would be nice..if you paste the error you are getting

Comment: I first downvoted, but now when I re-read the question, it is actually quite clear - just that the subject was quite bad. You should *not* ask a question with a title "there is something wrong but I don't know what that is"...

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE type='pic' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $queryStart, 5");
```

Problems were:

- The `AND type="pic"` was not included in the string, or concatenated in any way
- Your `AND type="pic"` is clearly intended to fit in a `WHERE` clase, which should come after the `FROM` clause, but before the `ORDER` clause
- You only need an `AND` to concatenate multiple `WHERE` clauses - you only have one.

Answer (score 1):

the `WHERE` clause must come first before `ORDER` and `LIMIT`

```
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE type='pic' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$queryStart.", 5");
```

Answer (score 1):

`AND type="pic"` is super wrong. You should put it inside the query string. Also a where clause does not appear after `LIMIT` clause. `LIMIT` clause should be at the last. So use this query.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE type='pic' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $queryStart, 5);
```

**Note:** Don't use `mysql_*` functions. They are [deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli)